# How to get ID of Tab of exist url

Tags: api, google-chrome-extension

i want to get ID of Tab of exist url
For exemple i have 3 tabs in chrome
tab 1 is youtube
tab 2 is google
tab 3 is twitter
and i want get id of tab already existed url google com

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
// get all the tabs, you can also limit it to the current window if you wish
// chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, ...)
chrome.tabs.query({}, tabs => {

  // loop through the tabs
  for (const tab of tabs) {
    if (tab.url === 'theOneYouWant) {
      // do whatever needed with tab.id

      // break/stop the loop
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

You can change the code to to check for the domain (not the whole URL) or any other relevant criteria.

Answer (score 0):

**Use [chrome.tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) in your extension page** such as the browserAction popup or the background script.

manifest.json:

```js
"permissions": ["tabs"]
```

Simplest case - no variations in domain name:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({url: 'https://www.youtube.com/*'}, tabs => {
  // use 'tabs' inside the callback
});
```

Simple case - variations in sub-domain but the TLD (top level domain) name doesn't have variations:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({url: 'https://*.twitter.com/*'}, tabs => {
  // use 'tabs' inside the callback
});
```

Tough case - TLD varies:

```js
const RE_ALL_GOOGLE = /^https:\/\/(www\.)?google\.([a-z]{2,3}|com?\.[a-z]{2})\//;
// the tabs API doesn't accept wildcards in TLD so we need to enumerate all tabs
// and we restrict the list to https-only as an optimization for the case of many open tabs
chrome.tabs.query({url: 'https://*/*'}, tabs => {
  const googleTabs = tabs.filter(({url}) => RE_ALL_GOOGLE.test(url));
  // use 'googleTabs' here inside the callback
});
```

You can write a more restrictive regexp by using the [full list of all Google domains](https://www.google.com/supported_domains) and a RegExp generator like [this one](http://kemio.com.ar/tools/lst-trie-re.php).

---

**Content scripts can't use chrome.tabs directly** so you'll need to do it via a background script.

content script:

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  action: 'getTabs',
  url: 'https://*/*',
  // messaging can't transfer regexps so we convert it to a string
  pattern: /^https:\/\/(www\.)?google\.([a-z]{2,3}|com?\.[a-z]{2})\//.source,
}, tabs => {
  // use 'tabs' inside the callback
});
```

manifest.json:

```js
"permissions": ["tabs"],
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": false
}
```

background.js:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (msg.action === 'getTabs') {
    chrome.tabs.query({url: msg.url}, tabs => {
      if (msg.pattern) {
        const re = new RegExp(msg.pattern);
        tabs = tabs.filter(({url}) => re.test(url));
      }
      sendResponse(tabs);
    });
    // keep the reponse channel open since the chrome.tabs API is asynchronous
    return true;
  }
});
```